# how to merge two Associative Arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

i need to merge two Associative Arrays with one.
1. first array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c_id] => 743
            [userid] => 570c842ce6073
            [postid] => 5761a6fb30cfa
            [comment] => demo testing
        )

);
```

2. second array

```
Array
(
    [hip] => 120
)
```

i need like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c_id] => 743
            [userid] => 570c842ce6073
            [postid] => 5761a6fb30cfa
            [comment] => demo testing
            [hip] => 120
        )

);
```

how can i write php code

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow... You use a keyboard, computer and editor to write php code. :-) No, really, this question is so simple that you should be able to find the answer yourself, once you have the required three items. Something like: `$array1[0]->hip = $array2['hip'];`, but I think you want a more general answer? Have a look at the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
<?php 

// Object
$object = new stdClass();
$object->c_id = 743;
$object->userid = '570c842ce6073';
$object->comment = 'demo testing';

// Array containing object
$array1[0] = $object;

// Associative array
$array2 = array(
    'hip' => 120,
    'dummy1' => 100,
    'dummy2' => 200
);

// Copying values from array2 to the object in array1 on key 0
foreach($array2 as $input => $key) {
    $array1[0]->$key = $input;
}

// View array1 with new values from array2
print_r($array1);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to merge 2 arrays here, you want to add array key/values into an object.

Merging array is done by [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php) and would result to

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c_id] => 743
            [userid] => 570c842ce6073
            [postid] => 5761a6fb30cfa
            [comment] => demo testing
        )
    [hip] => 120
);
```

With code you provide you have to loop on your 2nd array and insert key/values on you 1st array 1 item (which is your object)

```
$obj = $array1[0];
foreach($array2 as $key => $value){
  $obj->$key = $value;
}
```

Careful, this loop will overwrite the property if it already exist in array1